# Symfony 4 install there is no "public" folder.Just "vendor/".(Could not open input file: bin/console)

Tags: php, installation, symfony4

I want to learn Symfony Framework but i can't run it.Composer latest version.And i use this command to install framework as Docs said.Than i use this command for start the server in "project/" folder but i get that error `"Could not open input file: bin/console"`.

```
duhan@dbalci:/var/www$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton project


Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.5)
  - Installing symfony/skeleton (v4.0.5): Loading from cache
Created project in project
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 21 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.0.78): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/console (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/routing (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/framework-bundle (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/debug (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/finder (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/cache (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/dotenv (v4.0.8): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

duhan@dbalci:/var/www$ cd project/
duhan@dbalci:/var/www/project$ php bin/console server:run
Could not open input file: bin/console
```

There is just "vendor/" folder but i seen in tutorials there is more.
"ls -l" output :

```
duhan@dbalci:/var/www/project$ ls -l
total 60
-rw-rw-r-- 1 duhan duhan  1231 Apr 13 13:30 composer.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 duhan duhan 48230 Apr 13 13:30 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 duhan duhan     3 Apr 13 13:30 symfony.lock
drwxrwxr-x 5 duhan duhan  4096 Apr 13 13:30 vendor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like Composer hasn't fully executed the functionality in the symfony/flex plugin. The only reason I can think of that would cause this is if you've got plugins disabled globally (you can diagnose this by running `composer config -l` and seeing if it mentions `no-plugins` anywhere)

I can replicate your directory structure by running:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton project --no-plugins
cd project
composer install
```

This will create an empty symfony.lock file, but not unpack any of the installed Symfony recipes.

From here, you should be able to complete the installation by running

```
composer fix-recipes
```

in the project folder. This will finish unpacking all of the installed recipes, including creating the missing directory structure.